# function for the sum of all even numbers

Tags: javascript

I wanted to create a function which take a string of any numbers and characters as a one parameter. the task is  to find all the even numbers(digits) and sum them up then display the total value in console.
**for example**, if the following string  is passed to this function as a one parameter ("112,sf34,4)-k)") the result should be :    **The sum of  all even  numbers: 10**

So far I have come with solution and solve after this. Help me. Thanks in advance.

```
function functionFive(str) {
    const string = [...str].map(char => {
        const numberString = char.match(/^\d+$/)
        if (numberString !== null){
            const number = parseInt(numberString)
            return number
        }

    const num = string.map(number=>{
        if (number !== undefined && number%2 === 0){
             console.log(number)
        }
    })
}
functionFive("sau213e89q8e7ey1")
```

Comment: Are you talking just single digit numbers? Ie `112` is `1`, `1` and `2`

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything. On top of that, you have unmatched brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below code help you with minimum loops

```js
function sumEven(s) {
  return s
    .split("")
    .filter(x => x % 2 === 0)
    .reduce((acc, val) => acc + Number(val), 0);
}

console.log(sumEven("112,sf34,4)-k)"));
```

Answer (score 9):

Would this help?

```js
function sumEven(s) {
  return s.split('').map(x=>+x).filter(x=>x%2==0).reduce((a,b)=>a+b)
}

console.log(sumEven('idsv366f4386523ec64qe35c'))
```

Comment: `+x` was classic:-)

Answer (score 2):

I'd just search for all even single digit numbers with the exception of zero (because it will not contribute to the sum) with a regex and sum the resulting array, ie

```js
const functionFive = str => (str.match(/2|4|6|8/g) || [])
  .reduce((sum, num) => sum + parseInt(num, 10), 0)

console.info(functionFive("sau213e89q8e7ey1"))
```

Comment: I know it makes no difference for the sum, but zero is an even single digit number as well.

Comment: Zero is even, that's the only reason why I wrote my comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_zero

Comment: @Megapteranovaeangliae I wasn't aware of that, cheers. I've update my answer to explain why zero isn't included

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
   function functionFive(str){
     return  str.split('')
            .filter((el)=> !isNaN(el) && el % 2 === 0)
            .reduce((acc,cur)=> parseInt(acc) + parseInt(cur));
          }
       console.log(functionFive("112,sf34,4)-k"))
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

```js
function isNumber(char) {
  return parseInt(char) !== 'NaN';
}

function functionFive(str) {
   // 1. split str into array
   const charList = str.split('');

   // 2. filter out non-numbers
   const numberList = str.filter(isNumber);

   // 3. return the sum of the numbers using reduce
   return numberList.reduce((acc, curr) => curr % 2 === 0 ? acc + curr : acc, 0);
}
functionFive("sau213e89q8e7ey1")
```

Hope it helps and its easy to understand :)

Answer (score 1):

Using Regular expressions

```
const functionFive = str => (str.match(/\d/g)||[]).reduce((a,b)=>a=parseFloat(a)+(parseFloat(b)%2==0?parseFloat(b):0),0);

console.log(functionFive("112,sf34,4)-k)"))
```

Comment: This will fail if there are no digits in the string

Answer (score 1):

A one line solution to get the result. Hope this helps

```js
let text = "2543sadadfh7896";
let evenNums = text.match(/\d+/g);
let result = evenNums!== null ? evenNums.join().split('').filter(i => i%2 ===0).reduce((a, b) => Number(a) + Number(b)) : 0;

console.log(result)
```